Format Bartender Date as MMM dd yyyy
I'm currently working on formatting dates in my labels, but I'm having trouble getting the desired format.
I want to display a date in the 'MMM dd yyyy' format (for example, 'Apr 22 2024'), but despite my efforts, the format doesn't print correctly during the printing process. I believe the ISO file in custom format cannot be written in this way.
